# Entering an input within brackets

Tags: matlab, input, special-characters, user-input, brackets

Is it possible in matlab to enter an input within brackets such as:

Enter an input: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]

I tried everything and nothing works, must be exactly like that where the user input is entered in real time within brackets

Comment: I don't understand what your desired output is.

Comment: it's a desired input, so your input statement should say: Enter an input (within brackets): [ => user input 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 <= ] with the brackets, I know it's weird, I just want to know if it's possible because I think somebody is trying to doop me. If it is how to do it?

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything. What are you expecting to be returned to the workspace? An array? A string?

Comment: Anything, I don't care whether a string or a matrix is fine either

Comment: That would be done with `x = input('Enter an input (within brackets) ');` or `x = input('Enter an input (within brackets) ', 's');` The result would be in variable `x`, either as an array or as a string

Comment: So there is no way, to put a bracket in front of the user input while he is inputting and one bracket after (still while he is inputting)?

Comment: So was _that_ what you wanted? Please reword your question text; it's totally unclear

Answer (score 0):

This returns a string in variable `s`. The opening bracket is directly in the prompt string. The closing bracket is printed using a *delete* character (code point 8) to move to the preceding line.

```
s = input('Enter an input: [','s'); disp([8 ']']);
```

Example run. User input is just the numbers separated by spaces.

[image]